# How to catch click on flash player?

Tags: javascript, flash

I`m using SWFObject for flash player on my webpage.
Player as usual has buttons like Play, Stop, Pause etc.
I need to catch moment, when my user click on any button and i need to execute some JS-function in this time.
Sorry for my english and thanks a lot in advance.
P.S. I dont have sources of my swf file.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, this is done via the `getURL()` function. You need to define the following in the action script of the flash file:

```
this.onClick = function(){ 
    getURL("javascript:yourFunctionName();");
};
```

This means you can't just take any flash file and make it call JS functions, it must be defined within the flash file itself.

If I am wrong, I'd love to hear how this can be done more generically without editing the flash itself.

Answer (score 3):

Calling a javascript function from flash can also be achieved using [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

Comment: One moment here: i dont have sources of my flash web player.

Comment: Definitely right, though -- ExternalInterface is the way to go when you have access to the source.  It's a beautiful thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method onPress.

Example

[button_name].onPress = function(){

//right here the stuff you wanna do

}

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...

At the risk of going out on a limb, I actually don't think there's any way, within the confines of cross-browser Javascript proper, to hook into specific Flash player activity like that.  In fact I'd be very surprised indeed if there were -- although I'd love to hear otherwise from someone more knowledgeable than me. :)

Assuming that's true, other than by some combination of listening (in the Javascript running in the context of your page) for focus and click events raised by the ActiveX/plug-in object itself (which probably wouldn't be very specific or dependable -- I don't even think click events get raised ), I doubt you'd have much luck.

From what brief testing I've done so far:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.onclick = function()
    {
        alert("Clicked the page!");
    }

    document.getElementById("mySWFObjectID").onfocus = function()
    {
        alert("Focused the player!");
    }

    document.getElementById("mySWFObjectID").onclick = function()
    {
        alert("Clicked the player!");
    }
}
```

... the player doesn't seem to be bubbling click events up to the page; in IE, the focus event fires, but not in Firefox, and only once, when the control gains focus. So aside from writing, maybe, a browser plug-in of some kind, to get you some lower-level access than what's exposed at the Javascript level, you might be out of luck on this one.

But again, if there's anyone out there who knows otherwise...